# Print documents via Wpf-controls and convert to XPS

Tags: wpf, xaml, printing, wpf-controls, xps

I'm trying to convert XAML control to XPS document, but i'd like to do this in batch mode - render control in memory and print it to XPS without rendering it on the screen. This project should work even without GUI.

I've read [Related topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502198/convert-wpf-xaml-control-to-xps-document), but it's not working properly. I can create control, set DataContext, but output xps is empty. If i render control on the screen and then print it, everything is ok, but if i'd like to do this in batch mode, i got empty document (there was only static labels etc.)

How can i force control to bind controls with data?

Next hard part would be: how can i add my custom header on each page if i print long-multi-page control? (ex. list?)

Comment: I'd suggest strongly breaking out that second question as it is a much more complex issue.

Comment: BTW, the second question, the only thing I've ever seen come close to solving that issue was discussed in this blog post from '07.  You can try to ask to see if there have been any updates since then.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2007/03/10/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm skipping your second question as it is complex enough to be a standalone.

I faced the same issue, but it may be caused by a couple of different things.

If the issue is because the bindings haven't been "tripped" yet, the solution is slightly hacky but is easy to do if you control the DataContext type.  You just add a public or internal method to your type that allows you to fire off PropertyChanged events for each public property.  Here's an example:

```
public interface IForceBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  void ForceBindings();
}

public class MyDataContext : IForceBinding
{
  public event PropertyChanged;
  private string _text;
  public string Text
  {
    get{return _text;}
    set{_text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text");}
  }
  public void ForceBindings()
  {
    OnPropertyChanged("Text");
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  { 
    // you know the drill
  }
}
```

then, you can use it thusly:

```
public void Print(MyDataContext preconfiguredContext){
  var page = new MyWpfPage();
  page.DataContext = preconfiguredContext;
  preconfiguredContext.ForceBindings();
  // write to xps
```

If that isn't working, you might be encountering a bug where the bindings on the first page never show up.  I'd have to dig for awhile before I can re-find the solution to that.

Comment: I've tried update Bindings via NotifyChange but it's not working :( Still this same problem. I looks like WPF don't want to render this control, because it wasn't shown anywhere...

Comment: @simon try adding two pages to the XPS document.  Do you see the second page?

Comment: @simon I ask because, depending on how you do this, the first page may sometimes not be "visible" in the xps doc.  Got a fix for that, if that's the case...

Comment: Right now i'm using my own implementation of DocumentPaginator and it works almost perfect... almost because i can't get size of my control (part of XPS). I have UserControl. After create it and set DataContext i can't find out how check ActualHeight of this element. Right now i have to render each control in Viewbox, check it's size and check if i can put it on current or next page.