# How to create XPS file silently?

Tags: wpf, xps

I have UIElement(Grid) with many components on it. 
I want to save it as XPS document but without seeing any popup windows like SaveDialog Window.
How to do that?

I have for now something like this:

```
System.Printing.PrintQueue queue; //as "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter writer = 
       PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
writer.Write(myUielement);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert WPF (XAML) Control to XPS Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502198/convert-wpf-xaml-control-to-xps-document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write any UI element directly to an XPS document without using the "print" functionality. Use the `XpsDocument` and `XpsDocumentWriter` classes as dictated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502198/convert-wpf-xaml-control-to-xps-document).