# How to export FlowDocument to DOC(x) or XLS

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office, document

In my program I generate some reports in `FlowDocument` and display it with `DocumentViewer` control.
Now I need to add more export opportunities. I use iTextSharp to export in PDF, and I can save to XPS natively. Can I save a document directly to any office formats, DOC or XLS. Or maybe someone knows of a good library for converting from PDF / XPS in DOC or XLS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. As I can't export to Doc from WPF automatically, I reproduced my page layout with [DocX Library](http://docx.codeplex.com/). This is really awesome and simple library that don't required MSOffice installed to create Word 2007/2010 files.

Comment: How, using DocX Library, does one convert from FlowDocument to docx?

Comment: Yep, Gusdor raises a good point. Also, apart from the "stay on topic" reason, using FlowDocument has the very robust advantage of starting from a Microsoft-supported feature while that library appears to be third-party with an unknown future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're looking for an answer, so I'll be brief. You can use the [Microsoft Interop assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create Word documents. It's no menial task, but in my opinion, it's easier than using iTextSharp. They come with Visual Studio.

To create XPS documents, you'll need to generate `FixedDocument` objects from your `FlowDocument`, but from there, it's only a few lines of code. Eric Sink has a nice article that you can find [here](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/B_Printing.html). This is also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502198/convert-wpf-xaml-control-to-xps-document) posted here.

Comment: I haven't problems with export to XPS from WPF. I have problems with export to DOC.