# How can I create document reports in wpf and c# with content that includes formatted text and some basic charts?

Tags: c#, wpf, report, document

I would like to create a simple report that consists mainly of text and some charts. The application is like a wizard form, that has user enter information and create a word  or similar document report in the end. There will be some charts that will be drawn from the information entered that should be displayed in the report as well.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a FlowDocument and inside it you can put an **InlineUIContainer**
with the controls you need:

Example of InlineUIContainer with inside a textbox:

```
<InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Bottom">
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Comm8RelGest}" />
</InlineUIContainer>
```

Example of InlineUIContainer with inside a chart:

```
<InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Bottom">
       <crt:Chart Title="My Chart">
             <crt:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
       </crt:Chart>
</InlineUIContainer>
```

Here some documentation about InlineUIContainer inside a FlowDocument:
[InlineUIContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [FlowDocumen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)t or [FixedDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.  They do a lot of work for you, but creating what you describe would still require considerable coding.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to include charts in FixedDocument?

Comment: It's been a while since I've messed with it but you should be able to embed just about anything you can in HTML or Word.  The difference is that flow documents are non-paged and dynamically lay out their elements based on available space.  Fixed documents are more Word or PDF like, they are page oriented and elements stay where you put them.

Comment: thanks, btw, since you mention word-like, can you export to word from a Fixed document?

Comment: I believe you can, you might want to take a look at http://www.bradcurtis.com/document-and-report-generation-using-xaml-wpf-data-binding-and-xps/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827573/how-to-export-flowdocument-to-docx-or-xls

Comment: Thanks! much appreciated, that looks like exactly what I want.