# Printing a list in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, printing

I have long listbox with around 250+ items. It is wrapped with some labels inside a `Grid` which is again wrapped inside a `ScrollViewer`. I am using the following code to print the contents of my grid.

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
printDlg.PrintVisual(grid1, "Grid Printing.");
```

But, it prints all the 250+ items on a single page thereby making everything too small. Why does it not automatically resize automatically? What can I do to achieve proper scaling and pagination?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Just added the following code and now the size is fine.

```
Size pageSize = new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
                // sizing of the element.
                gridinner.Measure(pageSize);
                gridinner.Arrange(new Rect(5, 5, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
```

**But it still prints the content on the first pag**e.

Comment: because `PrintVisual` make the image and then print ... So it fits the image in one page and print it accordingly. Fo normal printing you need to use other Libs

Comment: Can you suggest any such Libraries?

Comment: This question may be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502198/convert-wpf-xaml-control-to-xps-document You can try to covert controls into XPS and then print it.